# C# Eventbrite Create Event

Tags: c#, api, eventbrite

I am attempting to integrate with the Eventbrite API, I am just trying to create an event using RestSharp.

```
// Request to create an event.
var restClient = new RestClient("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/");
```

This is the base url I am using {MyOrganiserID} and MyToken to replace my actual token.

```
var createEventRequest = new RestRequest("organizations/{MyOrganiserID}/events", Method.POST);
createEventRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MyToken");
createEventRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

createEventRequest.AddQueryParameter("event.name.html", "My Event is good mate");
createEventRequest.AddQueryParameter("event.start.utc", "2019-12-12T18:00:00Z");
createEventRequest.AddQueryParameter("event.start.timezone", "Australia/Melbourne");
createEventRequest.AddQueryParameter("event.end.utc", "2019-12-12T20:00:00Z");
createEventRequest.AddQueryParameter("event.end.timezone", "Australia/Melbourne");
createEventRequest.AddQueryParameter("event.currency", "AUD");

IRestResponse createEventRestResponse = restClient.Execute(createEventRequest);
var requestContent = createEventRestResponse.Content;
```

I have also tried to send the parameters in the requestbody using AddBody and AddXMLBody from the RestSharp API.

```
createEventRequest.AddBody("event.name.html=<p>A DARQ Room Production Woof Woof</p>&event.start.utc=2019-12-12T18:00:00Z&event.start.timezone=Australia/Melbourne&event.end.utc=2019-12-12T20:00:00Z&event.end.timezone=Australia/Melbourne&event.currency=AUD");
```

```
createEventRequest.AddXmlBody("event.name.html=<p>A DARQ Room Production Woof Woof</p>&event.start.utc=2019-12-12T18:00:00Z&event.start.timezone=Australia/Melbourne&event.end.utc=2019-12-12T20:00:00Z&event.end.timezone=Australia/Melbourne&event.currency=AUD");
```

I've also tried to add the fields via the AddParameters method as well.

```
createEventRequest.AddParameter("event.name.html", "This is a good event mate");
createEventRequest.AddParameter("event.start.utc", "2019-12-12T18:00:00Z");
createEventRequest.AddParameter("event.start.timezone", "Australia/Melbourne");
createEventRequest.AddParameter("event.end.utc", "2019-12-12T20:00:00Z");
createEventRequest.AddParameter("event.end.timezone", "Australia/Melbourne");
createEventRequest.AddParameter("event.currency", "AUD");
```

With the AddQueryParameter I get a 401 Unauthorised I have tried putting the token as a query parameter aswell and it still says I'm unauthorized.

And another error I get is

```
{
    "status_code": 403, 
    "error_description": "You do not have permission to access the resource you requested.", 
    "error": "NOT_AUTHORIZED"
}
```

When I send the parameter via the request body.

Any help anyone can provide would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: How did you retrieve this token? And for how long is it valid?

Comment: Retreved it via OAuth2 I've just removed that code for clarity purposes.

Comment: The token is valid until the user changes their password.

Comment: can you verify that expiration with https://jwt.io? Normally OAuth2 tokens are short lived.

Comment: The access code expires but the access token does not expire until the user changes their credentials.